# Sheets - Split cell into list(Array) and find average - Not across columns

Tags: google-sheets

If I have cell A1 with value **73562**

How can I split it so that I create an array that I can then find the average of?

so for cell A1 I want the answer in B1 to be **4.6**.

That is the average of

```
[7,3,5,6,2]
```

I thought array syntax on split would work, but it errors.

```
=AVERAGE({SPLIT(L4,'')})
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=average(split(regexreplace(A1&",","(\d)","$1,"),","))
```